# String between Comma and Comma+space

Tags: java, string

I have countries in a

```
String countryNames ="CHINA,RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE,INDIA,MALAYSIA";
```

Here RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE belong to same country name, I want to split country by country, I am using StringTokenizer,

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(countryNames,",");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
            String countryName = st.nextToken();
            countriesList.add(countryName);
        }
```

But the above code fails when I have to split RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE, Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just use a different separator (like `;`) as a delimiter?

Comment: getting these values from jsp page(form:select multiple)

Comment: While getting the current token you can check next token also and append to the previous token if both are of same country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code helps you to solve your problem, Code is not optimized try to make it small and optimized.:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String countryNames = "CHINA,RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE,INDIA,MALAYSIA";
    List<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
    char[] chararray = countryNames.toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    for (char ch : chararray)
    {
      if (endIndex > 0)
      {
        //Find only those commas whose nearby with characters only. Example : E,I
        if (ch == ',' && (chararray[endIndex - 1] >= 'A' && chararray[endIndex - 1] <= 'Z')
            && (chararray[endIndex + 1] >= 'A' && chararray[endIndex + 1] <= 'Z'))
        {
          str = "";
          for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
          {
            str += chararray[i];
          }
          countriesList.add(str);
          startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        }
      }
      endIndex++;
    }
    str = "";
    //Add last segment of the string.
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
      str += chararray[i];
    }
    countriesList.add(str);

    //Displaying list.
    for (String s : countriesList)
      System.out.println(s);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions as the delimiter

set your delimiter to "/\S,/" and it will find only commas that are preceded by a non-whitespace character.

EDIT: You can use this for replace as well, this means you can replace all the commas you want to use as delimiters with some other, more appropriate delimiter (like a semicolon)

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(countryNames.replace("/\\S,/", ";"),";");
```

The double backslash is there so that the string that is processed will have /\S,/ in it

Comment: Oh good point, well you could just use the same regex expression for the replace command and replace all of the "good" commas with semicolons and split on that

Answer (score 0):

The code will always fail since `,` is ambiguous. The only way to parse this properly *might* be since `THE,` has a space before it, to distinguish that it is part of the *previous* token.

So

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(countryNames,",");

while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    String countryName = st.nextToken();
    if(countryName.startsWith(" ")) // or any other way to distinguish it, possibly with a regex itself
    {
        String prevToken = countriesList.get(countriesList.size() -1);
        String completedCountry = merge(prevToken, countryName); // write some code to merge it to the proper countryname.
        replace(countriesList, prevToken, completedCountry); // replace  'prevToken' value with 'completedCountry' in 'countriesList'
    } else {
        countriesList.add(countryName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method to solve this problem.

```
String countryNames ="CHINA,RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE,INDIA,MALAYSIA";

String str[]=countryNames.split(",");

for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    System.out.println(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: split?? RUSSIAN FEDERATION, THE I want this to be as single, How will your code work?